# C printf wont print before scaning next number

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, scanf

I got this piece of code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  int number, S;
  float MO;


  S = 0;

  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    printf("AAA %d\n", i );
    scanf("%d\n", &number);
    S = S + number;
  }

  MO = S/10;

  printf("%d , %f \n",S , MO );
  return 0;
}
```

when the execution starts, AAA 0 is printed.I then give my first number.After that, i am expecting to see AAA 1 , but this will be printed only after i give my second number.
Checked this here

[C/C++ printf() before scanf() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue)

but seems i can get none of these solutions work for me

Comment: `scanf("%d\n", &number);` -> `scanf("%d", &number);`

Comment: Indeed this solved the problem.Dont know how to choose this comment as answer though.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, you might add this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers claiming that this has something to do with flushing input or output are wrong. The problem has nothing to do with this. The appearance of the `\n` character at the end of the `scanf()` template string instructs `scanf()` to match and discard whitespace characters. It will do so until a non-whitespace character is encountered, or end-of-file is reached. The relevant part of the C11 Standard is §7.21.6.2 5:

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains
>   unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never
>   fails.

In OP's case, a second number must be placed in the input stream so that the first can be assigned. The second number then remains in the input stream until the next call to `scanf()`. In the case of the example given by Stephan Lechner, taking input from a file, there is a number in the input stream after each number to be assigned, until the last number (if there are exactly ten numbers), and then the `EOF` causes `scanf()` to return. Note that OP could also have signalled `EOF` from the keyboard after each input. Or, OP could enter all numbers on one line, with an extra number to signal end of input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

The solution is simply to remove the `\n` from the end of the `scanf()` template string. Whitespace characters at the end of such a template string are tricky, and almost never what is actually desired.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `\n` from the `scanf` format string:

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Comment: Why is this necesssary? If he presses Return after the number, won't that match the format string?

Comment: @Barmar No, the `\n` will match any amount of whitespace after the number. So it could match one newline or a hundred (and any number of spaces or tabs as well). The `scanf` won't return until it sees at least one non-whitespace character. And it won't see that non-whitespace character until you type a non-whitespace character and press enter.

Comment: That should be explained in the answer.

Comment: I answered a similar question a couple of weeks ago, regarding space in `scanf()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534295/c-programming-role-of-spaces-in-scanf/41534477#41534477 I didn't realize `\n` acted the same way.

Comment: @Barmar Yup, it's easy to miss, but there's a little note buried in the man page that says, *"White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input."* So it's a common mistake to expect a `\n` in the format to match a newline character, but in fact it's no different than just putting a space in the format string.

Answer (score 3):

`"\n"` waits for non-white-space.  Instead use `scanf("%d", &number)` [@Michael Walz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883012/c-printf-wont-print-before-scaning-next-number/41884819#comment70948318_41883012) and check its return value.

Let us break down `scanf("%d\n", &number);`

1. `"%d"` Scan for numeric text.  This specifier will allow leading white-space.  Once some non-numeric character is found, put that character back into `stdin`.  If valid numeric text for an integer was found, convert to an `int` and save to `number`.
2. `"\n"` Scan and discard 0 **or more** white-spaces such as `'\n'`, `' '`, and others.  **Continue scanning** until non-white-space is encountered, put that character back into `stdin`.

Now return the number of fields scanned (1).

---

Notice step 2.  User had to type in data after the <kbd>Return</kbd> or `'\n'`  to get `scanf()` to return.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the buffering of `stdout` which doesn't force a flush unless a `\n` is in the output or `fflush` is called specifically

Comment: Both `printf`s have a `\n`. The OP's problem is unrelated to the buffering of `stdout`.

Comment: The issue, in this case, is the OS buffering - ergo the fflush part of the answer

Comment: No, the issue is the `\n` in the `scanf`. The issue has nothing to do with OS buffering or `stdout` or `fflush`.